# Apache Jmeter + Random Double

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to generate random double numbers in JMeter?

I tried to use the `Random` in the config element where i have defined the

```
Minimum value: 47.9999  (RND1)
Maximum value: 30.9999  (RND2)
```

Then in the selected Prepared Selected Statement i placed this values:

```
Parameter values: ${RND1},${RND1},${RND2}
Parameter types: DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE
```

But it seems not work, because i receive an error:

> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert class
>   java.lang.String to SQL type requested due to
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException - For input string: "${RND1}"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `${RND1}` is not expanded to it's value in your JDBC Request because it wasn't initialized Random Variable config item - because the last one is to generate only integer values (as well as jmeter's [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function).

To generate random double values in defined range you can use schema like below:

**1.** Define MIN and MAX range values as variables in [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

`RND1    37.9999
RND2    41.9999`

**2.** Generate random double value in range RND1..RND2 using e.g. [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler):

- Parameters: `${RND1},${RND2}`
- Script (java code):

```
import java.util.*;

String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

double rangeMin = Double.valueOf(params[0]);
double rangeMax = Double.valueOf(params[1]);
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();

vars.put("RND",randomValue.toString());

//System.out.println(randomValue);
```

Adding [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler), with `Jmeter variables = true` let you see generated values for debugging purposes.

**3.** Refer generated random value as `${RND}` for further use (in JDBC Request in your case)